# Bluetooth Call Receive with 32feet.net and c#

Tags: c#, .net, bluetooth, 32feet

I need to perform two task in c# 
1) with USB cable
2) with Bluetooth

i want to dial and receive calls from smart android mobile. Mobile can be connected with USB cable or Bluetooth. I can dial and receive calls using USB cable by AT commands. Android mobile is connected as USB GSM Modem (Virtual com port). AT+CLIP=1 give a number information along with RING when someone is calling. So i can attend call by viewing a specific number. This part is working Well.

The second part is same thing with Bluetooth. I used 32feet.net for dialing a call. I am able to make a call after going through these forums links

[Bluetooth dial with 32feet.net and c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960208/bluetooth-dial-with-32feet-net-and-c-sharp)

[Bluetooth communication from PC to mobile phone, use laptop speaker and mic during voice call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27330172/bluetooth-communication-from-pc-to-mobile-phone-use-laptop-speaker-and-mic-duri)

[Get Data from Bluetooth device in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22668912/get-data-from-bluetooth-device-in-c-sharp)

now i am not able to get any information when anyone is calling on Bluetooth
i am using hand free profile as using serial port i get an error may be my mobile not support Bluetooth virtual com port.

can anyone point out me how i can get information that which one is calling or invoke some function when anyone call. I need to get a number which one is calling that help me in decision to accepting or rejecting a call.

Comment: I slightly edited your question and removed unnecessary things, or that request "can someone help me" (which renders your question off topic here, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question ). But in order to receive real helpful feedback, please read [mcve] and add *real* code to your question. Linking to some site that probably has a ton of information, and then ask people here to digest all of that is a **no go**.

Comment: So, seriously: please turn to the [help] to *really* learn how/what to ask here.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth: use HandsFree Profile. It runs RFCOMM control channel that allows your application to place a call, handle incomming calls, 3-way calling and other things using AT commands (HFP is well documented so you can find all the commands in its specification). However Windows standard Bluetooth driver from Microsoft does not support connection to HFP Audio Fateway. You can do it with BlueSoleil only.

USB: There is no USB HFP profile. Android supports only DUN through USB so it can act as USB GSM Modem only and supports only modem commands. No voice and no other commands.